# When click, different content will shows up (content from database)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm creating a list of subjects when click it'll shows all the teachers that are teaching the subject. The subjects and teachers data are from MySQL database.

I've tried using javascript to do the "on click" function and php to retrieve the data from database but its not working.

```
        <?php do { ?>
        <?php do { ?>
        <script>
function showResult(b) {
  var res = document.getElementById('stafflist');
  if (b.classList.contains(<?php $row_Recordset1['subject'] ?>) = <?php $row_Recordset2['subject'] ?>) {
    res.innerHTML = <?php echo $row_Recordset2['StaffName'] ?>} 
</script>

<?php } while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)); ?>

<div class="subjectlist">
  <p onclick="showResult(this)" class="<?php $row_Recordset2['subject'] ?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset2['subject']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>

<p id="stafflist"></p>
```

Comment: Multiple php segments are missing `echo` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a JavaScript function on the "onclick" event that will use an AJAX call to populate the teachers that are teaching that subject.

Your PHP file should return a json with the list of teachers and you will use this json to populate the list.

Take this as an example:

```
function showResult(subject_id) {

    var url = "getResults.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {subject_id:subject_id},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        beforeSend: function() {
            //You can show a preloader here
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        //Hide the preloader
        //Populate the list
    }).fail(function() { 
        //Hide the preloader
        //Show an error message
    }); 
}
```